# ¿Cómo veo las diferencias en una edición que me hicieron?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, formato

He recibido [una edición en una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/362643/revisions), la cual dice *mejor formato, así evitamos hacer scroll hacia los lados*

¿Cuáles son las mejoras que se ha aplicado a mi código? Ya que a simple vista la publicación corregida la visualizo igual.

No sé si puede ser por que dejé demasiado espacio a la izquierda al insertar el código o hice otra cosa mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si en la revisión aprietas en "en paralelo" verás con más detalle qué se cambió:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te fijas, se movieron los comentarios a la línea superior de cada comando. Es decir, se pasó de:

```
DateTime fecha =  bla; //recoges el día seleccionado del monthCalendar en una variable DateTime
```

a

```
//recoges el día seleccionado del monthCalendar en una variable DateTime
DateTime fecha =  bla;
```